# If $A$ is a set of ordinals then $\bigcup A=\sup A$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Let  $A$ be a set of ordinals, I'd like to prove that $\bigcup A=\sup A$

The definitions I'm working with:

A set [of sets] $X$ is said to be *transitive* if $x \in X\implies x\subseteq X$

A set $X$ is said to be an *ordinal* if it is transitive and well ordered W.R.T. the relation  $\in$

I'm stuck at showing $\bigcup A$ must be an upper bound of $A$. If we have $a\in A$, I'd like to show this implies $a\in \bigcup A$, but all I've arrived at is  $a\subseteq  A$ (I have already shown $A$ itself must be transitive) and $a\subseteq \bigcup A$ (by definition). How does this get me $a\in \bigcup A$?

Comment: Do you know that $\alpha\in\beta$ and $\alpha\subsetneq\beta$ are the same for ordinals $\alpha,\beta$?

Comment: From $a\subseteq\bigcup A$ you cannot deduce $a\in\bigcup A$; think when $A$ contains a single ordinal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bigcup A$ is transitive: If $y\in x\in \bigcup A$, then $x\in z$ for some $z\in A$ and by transitivity of $z$, $y\in z$, hence $y\in\bigcup A$.

$\bigcup A$ is well-ordered by $\in$: let $B\subseteq \bigcup A$ be non-empty, say $b\in B$. Then $b\in  a$ for some $a\in A$. Then $a\cap B$ is a non-empty subset of $a$, hence has a minimal element $m$. Let $c\in B$. Then $c\notin m$ because $c\in m\in a$ would imply $c\in a\cap B$, contradicting minimality of $m$. As $m$ and $c$ are ordinals, this implies $m\in c\lor m=c$. Thus $m=\min B$.

Therefore $\bigcup A$ is an ordinal. So for $a\in A$, we have $a\subseteq \bigcup A$, and as $\bigcup A$ is an ordinal, this means $a\in\bigcup A\lor a=\bigcup A$.

Comment: Doesn't that only prove that $\bigcup A$ is an upper bound to $A$?

Answer (score 1):

You said that you proved that $ \cup A $ is transitive. Prove also that it is itself an ordinal. Show also that for ordinals $ \alpha $ and $ \beta $ that $ \alpha \leq \beta $ or $ \beta \leq \alpha $. From here you can conclude that $ a \leq \cup A $.